# PHP: How does php "see" an objects properties?

Tags: php, oop

I think this might be more a basic OOP question than one specific to php.

When I try to access an instantiated object's private property (`$myObj->$privateProp`) I get this error: `"Cannot access private property"`. Now I know I can't do this, but I'm curious how php knows this object has a private property named `privateProp`. I guess I was expected an error like `Undefined property` because the property shouldn't be visible?

Comment: The private property is likely declared as private since by default undeclared will be public. So asking how PHP knows makes little sense unless you are not specifically declaring it as private and yet it is somehow being seen that way. "How does PHP know" is kind of hard to ascertain what you mean. How does PHP also know that $ is the beginning of a variable? Because that's how the language interprets. It follows the rules it was given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP knows all, sees all. Or at least the System does.

The simplest example would be comparing it your own computer and it's operating system. If you mark a file as "hidden", the system hides it from YOU and other Users, but it knows it's there the whole time.

PHP is the over-arching controller, the master mind behind the script. It enforces the language specifications and rules of interaction amongst objects.

What your code is really doing is asking PHP to mark the object as having a private property, and thus protect it from outside the class/inheritance access. When something or someone tries to access it (including you), PHP kindly reminds you that you can't do that, because you already asked it to mark that property as private.

It also helps to understand that "private" does not mean secret! Using things like reflection you can access and change everything, anyway.

Private, public, constants, and the whole family is all about avoiding "side effects" and simplifying the use of objects (so you can just use getName() and not have to worry about the internals of how name is stored/retrieved/created), not about providing secrecy and security.

It's all about protecting you from doing something you would be best advised not to do, not to protect secrets from a malicious script or user that somehow managed to run arbitrary code on your system! PHP offers no protection from that - it's not what public/private/protected mean. Once you get past that sense of the words not applying to programming, things get a bit easier to understand!

Comment: Thanks, the idea that these are rules php is enforcing makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

When you var_dump() an object, you will get a list of all of it's properties no matter what the visibility. In reality, it should be thought of "accessibility" in the sense that you can't access a private property or see the value of that property, but you can see that that object has that property and that it is private.

Answer (score 0):

No need for that second $.

```
$myObj->privateProp
```

Your current code is using the value of $privateProp as the property name.

```
class bar {
    $foo = "bar";
}

$privateProp = 'foo';
echo $myObj->$privateProb; // "bar"
```

Comment: True, but completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: That's not what he was asking. Also it can be valid syntax if the variable matches the property name.